# Merge the [r-leaflet] and [leaflet-r] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[r-leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-leaflet) has 33 questions while [leaflet-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leaflet-r) has only 15 questions. Both refer to the leaflet package that integrates and control the open-source JavaScript Leaflet software in R.

Comment: Do you have any preferences which one will be the master tag?

Comment: @Andrew T. I would prefer keeping r-leaflet. It has the same convention than 1) other R packages (e.g., r-plotly, r-dygraphs) built on a Javascript library or 2) another package using r-leaflet (e.g., r-mapview).

Comment: Maybe most of the users of that tag might consider moving their stuff to [the GIS site](https://gis.stackexchange.com) anyway.

Comment: I agree that merging the tags into `r-leaflet` is a good idea.

Comment: I think I don't have enough rep to do it but hopefully, someone will do the merging.

Comment: Just some added context + confusion - there is both a `leaflet` package (https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet) and a `leafletR` package (https://github.com/chgrl/leafletR). Seeing as they have different implementations there may be a benefit to keep separate. I believe that the `r-leaflet` tag refers to the former (more popular) library, and I don't think that `leaflet-r` always refers to the latter, but you would have to go question by question to see.

Comment: @Chris there is already a `[tag:leaflet]` tag for the JavaScript library. I would say we ignore the lesser of the two R-related leaflet libraries as a cost of doing business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, they certainly are referring to the same package. I went through all the questions and I merged them both. That is, remove the [leaflet-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leaflet-r) from 15 questions, and added the [r-leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-leaflet) to 13 questions.

I also created a [synonym for both of them](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r-leaflet/synonyms).